# Can I append data to an existing table in Google Big query using the browser tool?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to append data to an existing table in Google Bigquery. Can I use the browser tool or is it only possible using the Python command line with the API?
Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in the UI. I've filed a feature request to add this support. You should be able to do an append by using the bq command line client or issuing api requests directly.